# Adding span to numbers using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, html

So I have been dabbling around in jQuery a bit this week. Trying to add some cool things to a wordpress theme I am currently working on.

With the help of this wonderful site, I received the following JS to wrap a span around numbers in a certain div. All was well until I started implementing more JS to find out this is actually causing my other JS to break.

```
//add span to numbers
var elem = document.getElementById('passage');
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace(/\b(\d+)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>');
```

However, I was informed since I am using jQuery, to take "document.getElementById" out and end up with this:

```
//add span to numbers
var elem = $( 'passage' );
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace( /\b(\d+)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>' );
```

I figured this would solve the situation with no luck. Any ideas of why this isn't working? Thanks

My end result is to be able to style numbers like this site does for their Bible verses: http://marshill.com/media/the-seven/lukewarm-in-laodicea-comfort-and-convenience-before-christ#scripture

Comment: `var elem = $( '#passage' );` use `#` for id selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're selecting by the `id` you need the CSS-alike `id` selector:

```
var elem = $('#passage');,
```

To select by class:

```
var elems = $('.className');
```

Using the `$('#passage')` selector, you end up with a jQuery object, rather than a DOM-node, so `$('#passage').innerHTML` (or `elem.innerHTML`) returns an error: [`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pGSDQ/1/) in Chromium 19.

To work around that, you can 'drop' back to a DOM-node with:

```
elem.innerHTML = $('#passage')[0].innerHTML.replace(/*...*/);
```

Or instead use jQuery:

```
elem.html(function(i,oldHTML){
    return oldHTML.replace( /\b(\d+)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>' );
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pGSDQ/).

References:

- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Thanks! Added that to it, but it still seems to be breaking all the other javascript. Any idea why?

Comment: Because jQuery objects aren't JavaScript DOM-nodes. See edit.

Comment: Added the example you used in JS Fiddle to my JS file and it still breaks it. I'm stumped on what in this code would do it. I am wrapping it in $(document).ready(function( $ ) { }); and calling for it externally.

Comment: Does it work for you in the JS fiddle? Are there errors in your JavaScript console when you place the above code into your page?

Comment: Yes it works in the fiddle. I have this error without your code:  
saying this is an illegal character
}​
main.js?ver=1.1 (line 86, col 1)

When I add in your code above I get this:
ReferenceError: jquery is not defined

Comment: You've definitely linked to jQuery? Have you made sure, if you're copying and pasting from JS Fiddle, to strip out all the white-space and re-indent as appropriate (JS Fiddle seems to use some funky non-visible whitespace characters, presumably for formatting/styling purposes)?

Comment: Yes definitely linked to jQuery correctly, using 1.7.2. All my other JS works perfectly fine. I made sure there weren't any whitespace when copying and pasting over. It's still not working though. I am coding all locally right now through MAMP. Would that have anything to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

For the first line, when working with ids, you want to prepend the string with a pound symbol; that is, `$('#passage')`.

For the second line, note that doing `$('#passage')` returns a jQuery object, so you can't use  standard methods on it. You should be using jQuery methods. The equivalent for `innerHTML` is [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

So you would want to do the following:

```
//add span to numbers
var elem = $( '#passage' );
elem.html(elem.html().replace( /\b(\d+)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>' ));
```

A little ugly, but it gets the job done. [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11111121/1467811) is slightly more eloquent.